# Unset shipping rate by code, in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, shipping-methods, table-rates

In some cases, I need to unset or reset shipping rates. So what I need to do is to get all available rates for given address in checkout, check some variables, and based on the result to unset some rates.

I'm trying to do this in an Observer like:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$quote = $event->getQuote();
$_rates = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getShippingRatesCollection();
foreach ($_rates as $key => $_rate):
    if($_rate->getCode() == 'xxx'){
        unset($_rates[$key]);
    }
endforeach;
```

The above example code is not working ok. I need to figure out how to unset the specific rate and update the rates collection in quote.

UPDATE-----
The unset() is returning an error:

```
Cannot use object of type Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Address_Rate_Collection as array
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error you are facing with this code?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but it's not working. Mabe because I have to re-apply the new rates array somewhere? idk

Comment: Which event you are using to call the observer function?

Comment: it's the "address_track_event"

Comment: I updated the question, adding an error that found that the unset() function causes